# How to concatenate millions array records to a single string faster?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to concatenate all values of a 2D array to a single String.
But performance is really impacted by size of the array (2800 X 1700).
I there a better way to do it ?

Thank you !

```
float[][] datas = obj.getMatrix();
String result = "";
int[] shape = {2800,1700};
for(k=0; k<shape[0]; k++){
   for(j=0; j<shape[1]; j++){
      result += (datas[k][j] + "").getBytes();
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I am using unidata netCDF java API to convert my data for ncML response.

My float[][] gives me some values that i want to add to a list.

Instead of doing a `String result = "10.0,15.1,45.6,25.4....."` I want to convert each value to byte[]. My string will look like `result = "[B@xxxxxxxx[B@xxxxxxxx[B@xxxxxxxx[B@xxxxxxxx...."`

Then,  I can convert my result into Base64 using `Base64.getEncoder().encode(result.getBytes())`

It will look like :

```
float[][] datas = obj.getMatrix();
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    int[] shape = {2800,1700};
    for(k=0; k<shape[0]; k++){
       for(j=0; j<shape[1]; j++){
          result.append((datas[k][j] + "").getBytes());
       }
    }
byte[] encodedByte = Base64.getEcnoder().encode(result);
String encodedStr = new String(result);
```

Then, when user get the response, he will decode the result, obtain the `"[B@xxxxxxxx[B@xxxxxxxx[B@xxxxxxxx[B@xxxxxxxx...."` responseand can identify values

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to all the comments, I understand what it cannot works.
Finally, I decided to just do : `result.append(datas[k][j] + ",");`

Comment: Use a StringBuilder instead of += operator. Each time you use +=, it requires a new String to be constructed.

Comment: a StringBuilder can be better but it really depends on what you have to do whith the string

Comment: In fact, i would like to concatenate all values into a single string, then convert my string to Base64. To send response to an http request

Comment: You may also use a StringWriter, if you prefer to use I/O facilities. It's especially interesting if you use String.format a lot, you can replace it with PrintWriter.printf and so you will maybe make less string constructions. Ultimately it probably uses StringBuilder at the end.

Comment: What is `(datas[k][j] + "").getBytes()` intended to do?  I understand `datas[k][j] + ""` ... but why are you calling `getBytes()` on it and then concatenating the resulting byte array?  Note that `result += /* a byte array */` is NOT going to append the string.  It is going to call `toString()` on the `byte[]` which while give you something like `[B@xxxxxxxx` where the `xxxxxxxx` is the byte array's identity hashcode.

Comment: @StephenC I hate to convert to Base64 the string result. It will be easier to retrieve values after decoding i it is byte[]. Because each value will have the same size, don't you think ?

Comment: What you are doing will NOT convert to Base64.  It will actually generate bunch of (basically) meaningless nonsense that is unrelated to the data that you are trying to ... encode.

Comment: If you want a **real** solution to your **real** problem, you need to explain exactly what you are trying to do here.   Are you trying to turn the array into readable text?  Or are you trying to encode it in binary ... and Base64 encode the binary?  Or ... something else?  Asking for a faster version of code that generates nonsense will just give you nonsense faster.

Comment: In fact there is no separator in `String result = "10.0,15.1,45.6,25.4....."` but i added it for lisibility

Comment: @user16320675 ` String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` with this ?

Comment: Ok ! I understand what you mean. If a get `[B@7ab2fe1`, there is no way to retrieve the original value ? I was thinking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use StringBuilder instead of string for result. This will reduce time to few secs.
as given below

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int[] shape = {2800,1700};
        for(int k=0; k<shape[0]; k++){
            for(int j=0; j<shape[1]; j++){
                result.append ((datas[k][j] + "").getBytes() );
            }
        }
```

Comment: This answers the OP's question.  But as the extensive comments (see above) explain, `(datas[k][j] + "").getBytes()` does not give something that the OP can actually use.